# Do I have to verify every parameter in a typescript overload?

Tags: typescript

I have two overloads of `update`. I can determine which overload I'm in by examining the first parameter:

```js
class CRC16 {
    update(buffer: number[], offset: number, length: number): number;
    update(data: number): number;
    update(buffer: number[] | number, offset?: number, length?: number) {
        if (Array.isArray(buffer)                              // Examine first parameter
              && offset !== undefined && length !== undefined) // These checks are redundant
            return length - offset;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}

const c = new CRC16();
console.log(
    c.update(1),
    c.update([1, 2, 3, 4], 1, 4));
```

Typescript gives `error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'` errors for `length` and `offset` if I comment out the redundant checks on the remaining parameters. (The redundant checks protect against an invocation like `c.update([1, 2, 3, 4])`, but typescript prohibits that anyways because it's not in any overload.) Is there a way to write this so I don't have to ceremoniously examine every parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all these 3 overloads are very similar and doesn't help much. Also, why would you rename a function parameter from `buffer` to `data`? If it is different, then there should be 2 functions.

Isn't this interface enough?

```
update(buffer: number[] | number, offset?: number, length?: number): number
```

This one captures all overloads above. Then, regarding skipping the checks in your code, I don't understand the point. TypeScript provides types to your code but it doesn't prevent you from checking your function inputs, as you would with plain js.

I think you are trying to put too many "responsabilities" on the TS side.

Comment: The prototypes are sufficient to tell typescript to reject an invocation with `buffer:number[]` but no `offset` or `length`. My question is why a test like `Array.isArray(buffer)` strongly types `buffer` in the nested code to be a `number[]` but doesn't type `offset` and `length` to be required. Typescript specifically *requires* me to test them even though the compatible prototype asserts their non-optionality.

Comment: Also, changing `data` to `buffer` to match the earlier prototype doesn't change the behavior. I believe that in real prototypes that folks will be using as documentation, it's better to have informative parameter names than to force all prototypes to use the same names (i.e. it's misleading to call a single number a "buffer').